# Show image in Lua

Tags: lua, minecraft, computercraft

Is there a way to show an image in Lua? I tried things like `load_image` (I saw something like that in the ComputerCraft documentation) but can't get it to work.

The purpose of this is to show an image in Computercraft, which uses LUA to write programs.

Comment: Please don't confuse between [Lua](https://github.com/LuaDist/lua) and [LUA](https://github.com/mniip/lua). Both languages are different. "Lua" is a name, and means "Moon" in Portugese. Please **do not write** it as _"LUA"_, which is both ugly and confusing, because then it becomes an acronym with [different meanings](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/lua) for different people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua (not LUA)  does not have such functionality on its own. You should consult Computercraft api docs, such as [this](http://computercraft.info/wiki/Paintutils_(API))